# ROS : Subscribe to topic in different namespace

Tags: ros, namespaces

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started to use ROS tonight.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

This is what I have already done :

- publish and subscribe to topic_b.
- publish to ns1/topic_a (I checked with `rostopic echo /ns1/topic_a`)
- publish to ns2/topic_a (I checked with `rostopic echo /ns2/topic_a`)
- subscribe to ns2/topic_a (`ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topic_a", 1000, callback);`)

What I don't know how to do :

- subscribe to ns1/topic_a from node_b.

After reading the tutorial, I tried this :

1/ In node_b.cpp, I subscribed to /topic_a_temp.

2/ In the launch file, inside the node_b tags, I added `<remap from="topic_a_temp" to="ns1/topic_a">`

But it doesn't work.

It may be very basic since I'm a beginner but I don't know how to read the ns1 topic from the ns2 node.

Thank you for your help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271335/ros-:-subscribe-to-topic-in-different-namespace/) by [Rorororororo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31985/rorororororo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-22**:
Namespace shouldn't be a problem, remap should work. Can you post output of `rostopic list` and `rqt_graph`

**Comment by [Rorororororo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31985/rorororororo/) on 2017-09-22**:
The rqt_graph looks like this : https://i.imgur.com/MC3GzwD.jpg
My remap looks litke this : https://i.imgur.com/TOWCf8i.png
rostopic list shows ns1/topic_a and ns2/topic_a (which are correctly filled when I echo). ns2/topic_a_temp is also shown but echo says, it says topic does not appear to be publ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. I resolved my issue. I missed a '/' at the beginning of the name in the remap.
I should have written : to="/ns1/topic_a".
Thanks !

---

Originally posted by [Rorororororo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31985/rorororororo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0